# passing an id in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If i start this question by showing you my routes: -

```
c:\Sites\work\easygifts>rake routes
         Prefix  Verb    URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
 writing_stores  GET     /stores/writing(.:format)        stores#writing
  office_stores  GET     /stores/office(.:format)         stores#office
    time_stores  GET     /stores/time(.:format)           stores#time
    home_stores  GET     /stores/home(.:format)           stores#home
wellness_stores  GET     /stores/wellness(.:format)       stores#wellness
  travel_stores  GET     /stores/travel(.:format)         stores#travel
    bags_stores  GET     /stores/bags(.:format)           stores#bags  
 leisure_stores  GET     /stores/leisure(.:format)        stores#leisure
   quote_stores  GET     /stores/quote(.:format)          stores#quote
         stores  GET     /stores(.:format)                stores#index
                 POST    /stores(.:format)                stores#create
      new_store  GET     /stores/new(.:format)            stores#new
     edit_store  GET     /stores/:id/edit(.:format)       stores#edit
          store  GET     /stores/:id(.:format)            stores#show
                 PATCH   /stores/:id(.:format)            stores#update
                 PUT     /stores/:id(.:format)            stores#update
                 DELETE  /stores/:id(.:format)            stores#destroy
        products GET     /products(.:format)              products#index
                 POST    /products(.:format)              products#create
     new_product GET     /products/new(.:format)          products#new
    edit_product GET     /products/:id/edit(.:format)     products#edit
         product GET     /products/:id(.:format)          products#show
                 PATCH   /products/:id(.:format)          products#update
                 PUT     /products/:id(.:format)          products#update
                 DELETE  /products/:id(.:format)          products#destroy
            root GET     /                                stores#index
```

The issue i am having is getting the :id into the 'quote' view.

I am wanting to see in my routes; quote_stores GET /stores/quote/:id(.:format) stores#quote Or something like it.

Can :id only be passed through CRUD?? I thought i could pass instance variables through pretty much anywhere so I wrote this in my view as the link to the view with the :id info passed into it.

```
    <% @products.each do |office| %>
        <div class="item">
            <%= link_to image_tag(office.image_url), image_path(office.image_url), class: 'fancybox' %>
            <p><strong><%= office.item_code%></strong>
            </br><em><%= truncate(office.title, length: 18) %></em></p>                 
            <p class="showArticle"><%= link_to 'Show Article', store_path(office) %></p>
            <p class="addTo"><%= link_to 'Price Info', quote_stores_path(office)  %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I am referring to the <%= link_to 'Price Info', quote_stores_path(office)  %> which upon click takes you to the correct view and in the URI path it even lists the correct :id however it does not pass into the view that :id's information.

My controller code is as follows: -

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
    add_breadcrumb 'home', :stores_path


  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @products = Product.find(params[:id])
      if @products.nil?
        redirect_to action: :index
      end
    add_breadcrumb 'Back', @products.section
  end

  def writing
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'writing').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'writing', writing_stores_path
  end

  def office
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'office').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'office', office_stores_path
  end

  def time
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'time').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'time', time_stores_path
  end

  def home
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'home').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'home', home_stores_path
  end

  def wellness
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'wellness').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'wellness', wellness_stores_path
  end

  def travel
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'travel').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'travel', travel_stores_path
  end

  def bags
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'bags').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'bags', bags_stores_path
  end

  def leisure
    @products = Product.where(:section => 'leisure').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    add_breadcrumb 'leisure', leisure_stores_path
  end

  def quote
        @products = Product.find_by(params[:id])
      if @products.nil?
        redirect_to action: :index
      end
  end
end
```

So apart from my code not being DRY, what am i missing here please?  What am i not understanding about :id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config/routes.rb`, you probably have this line:

```
resources :stores
```

Which creates routes for the standard CRUD actions of the `stores` resource. You can define additional actions for this resource which either apply to the collection (multiple products) or the members individually (a single product).

> *Please note that it would probably more logical to name the resource `products` rather than `stores`, since it seems to be handling `Products`.*

In your case, you'd want to define an additional *member* action. Since it applies to a single product, Rails will define a route which takes an `id` parameter:

```
resources :stores do
  member do
    get 'quote'
  end
end
```

This will generate the following route (`rake routes`):

```
quote_store GET    /stores/:id/quote(.:format)     stores#quote
```

Note that the route is called **quote_store**, the singular form rather than the plural.

Also see [the Rails guides for more information about collection and member routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes).

Comment: fivedigit, I hadn't heard of the member action, thank you for the resource link and the very clear answer that resolved the problem, very much appreciated.